# Assert RestAssured response body with Regex

Tags: java, regex, junit, rest-assured, hamcrest

I am trying to assert a timestamp field in json response body using RestAssured as part of my integration tests. I am not sure which is the right method to perform regex match

Here is the json response:

```
{
"timestamp": "2018-06-05T23:56:09.653+0000",
"status": 200,
"error": "None",
"message": "None"
}
```

This is my code for my RestAssured response assertion

```
String pattern = "^\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}T\\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}.\\d{3}(\\+|\\-)\\d{4}$";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
response.then().assertThat()
    .body("timestamp", matchesPattern(pattern)) //<= ERROR HERE
    .body("status", equalTo(999))
    .body("error", containsString("None"))
    .body("message", containsString("None"));
```

When I compile the above code I am getting error while verifying timestamp pattern

```
  required: java.lang.String,java.lang.CharSequence
  found: java.lang.String
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

I am not sure which method will support in hamcrest for regex pattern check.

Comment: @ScaryWombat, doesn't work. I've tried `pattern` and `r` inside `matchesPattern(..)`

Comment: reference https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=com.jayway.restassured.http.ContentType

Comment: Looks like I didn't added a right dependency. My hamcrest is 1.3 which doesn't support that

Comment: @ScaryWombat, I have answered my question. Thanks for your clue :-)

Comment: Glad it works for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is there are no right dependencies in my project. `org.hamcrest.core` doesn't have method for `matchesPattern`. After adding the below dependency the following import worked

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hamcrest/java-hamcrest -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
  <artifactId>java-hamcrest</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0.0</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

You need to import the below code

`import static org.hamcrest.text.MatchesPattern.matchesPattern;`

Comment: My editor turns "MatchesPattern" red when I paste that in. How, in 2019, do I `assertThat` a string matches a pattern?

Comment: Just a clue: Look at the import section of your code with `MatchesPattern`. Are you importing the right one?

Comment: My other hamcrest stuff imports correctly. I can `import static org.hamcrest.text`, but not `MatchesPattern`.